# EKS AMI kernel debug symbols

Tags: kernel, amazon-eks, amazon-ami, debug-symbols, debug-information

I need kernel debug symbols (debuginfo) of Amazon AMIs used for EKS clusters (e.g., 5.10.210-201.852.amzn2.aarch64). AWS does not include that in the AMIs, since it takes a lot of space. Does anyone know how I can obtain such debug symbols for Amazon AMIs? For example, Ubuntu keep such symbols in the package repository:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

But Amazon does not keep them in the package managers. I guess I need to compile the kernel again and enable debug symbols flag. Has anyone done such task? how can I do that?

I could find this repository:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami

but I did not manage to compile the kernel. I am not also sure if I am on a right track.